# What is the difference between bridge connection and internet connection sharing?

Tags: bridge, internet, connection-sharing

I have an external WiFi card, and I want to use it to share internet with my PS4, since I get bad signal in my room. But in the Network  settings there is the option to bridge the connection between the WiFi card and the Ethernet port and to share the internet connection with the Ethernet port, what is the difference?
And also, what happens if I share my internet connection from my external WiFi card with the internal one?

[ethernet sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OalIy.png)

[wifi sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaL7T.png)

[bridge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2QN4.png)

Comment: It would be best if you had a computer-savvy friend fix that for you because there's no single easy answer. But my one advice is - forget doing it with your computer. Get a WiFi repeater and pair it with your main router. Then place it between it and the console for optimal signal.

Comment: @Zdenek I can make it work, I just don't understand the difference

Comment: You may not be able to make it work because depending on the WiFi card drivers, it may only support offering a network via Ad Hoc (which the console may not accept), if any at all. To your question: A bridge is more like a hub; the result will still depend on services such as NAT and DHCP provided by your router. ICS, on the other hand, does these on its own allowing it to work when the computer is connected directly to the provider. ICS places a layer of NAT in between making it less compatible. Since you have the router, a bridge seems the lesser evil. But buggy on W10! Get the repeater.

Comment: Disregard that advice, it's wrong on many levels. WiFi Repeaters belong at the dump, they usually half the available bandwidth, and add latency. Bridge the WiFi connection with a dual band router that has third party firmware installed. Use one radio to connect to the main AP, use the other to re-broadcast. BTW, bridges are not like hubs at all, hubs are "bit spitters" and repeat everything received on one port out all others. Bridges are more like modern switches, and use a mac table for intelligent forwarding.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the difference, since you didn't get an answer:

> **Internet Connection Sharing:**
>
> With ICS, users can share a public Internet connection with a private
> home or small business network. In an ICS network, a single computer
> is chosen to be the ICS host. The ICS host has at least two network
> adapters: one connected to the Internet and one or more connected to
> the private network. All Internet-destined traffic flows through the
> ICS host. ICS uses Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) to
> assign private IP addresses on the network, and it uses Network
> Address Translation (NAT) to allow multiple computers on the private
> network to connect to the public network through the ICS host.
>
> **Network Bridge:**
>
> A network bridge is software or hardware that connects two or more
> networks so that they can communicate.
>
> People with home or small office networks generally use a bridge when
> they have different types of networks but they want to exchange
> information or share files among all of the computers on those
> networks.
>
> Here's an example. Let's say you have two networks: in one, the
> computers are connected with cables; and in the other, the computers
> are connected using wireless technology. The wired computers can only
> communicate with other wired computers, and the wireless computers can
> only communicate with other wireless computers. With a network bridge,
> all of the computers can communicate with each other.
>
> If you use the network bridge software built into Windows, you don't
> need to buy additional hardware.
>
> Regarding your environment, you may consider to create ICS.
>
> I’ve also included some related links for your reference:
>
> Internet Connection Sharing and Network Bridge in Windows Vista
>
> http://technet2.microsoft.com/WindowsVista/en/library/1720eb43-62cb-4327-9f26-8d7401d526531033.mspx?mfr=true
>
> Using ICS (Internet Connection Sharing)
>
> http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/Help/bfd3bd31-82f0-4b9c-9cde-fb92bc2b14771033.mspx

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dbe21a25-8190-40db-bed2-fe87aa8984cf/network-bridge-and-ics)